# How to return a value with Dispatcher.Invoke?

Tags: wpf, return, invoke, dispatcher

Anyone knows how to return a value from [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx).[`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) in [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)? I want to return the selected index for a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx).

Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

There's another way that returns value from  Invoke():

```
object oIsLoaded = container.Dispatcher.Invoke( new Func<bool> ( () =>
    {
        return container.IsLoaded;
    })
);
```

And by the way, chances are that the initial code (which is working with delegate) won't modify `oIsLoaded` at all; So I'd rather use a [`Func<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) for returning a value from that kind of function.

Answer (score 31):

```
int result = -1;

// this is synchronous
myCombo.Invoke(() => 
{
  result = myCombo.SelectedIndex;
});

return result;
```

This is, of course, kind of clunky.  Better design would be to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM, create a SelectedIndex property and bind the `SelectedIndex` property of your combo box to it.  INPC binds are thread-insensitive (3.5 or 4.0+, I don't remember which), so you can read and update these properties from different threads in your VM without worry.

Answer (score 2):

This is my method to retrieve selected value for a combobox, how can I say delegate to return value?

```
    private object getValueCB(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb)
    {
        object obj;


            if (!cb.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                obj = cb.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                  new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        obj = cb.SelectedValue;
                    }
                ));

                return obj;
            }
            else
            {
                return obj = cb.SelectedValue;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly but you can do this.

Dispatcher.Invoke() actually returns the return value from the delegate you call, so alter your delegate accordingly.

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Object The return value
>   from the delegate being invoked or
>   null if the delegate has no return
>   value.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591597.aspx)

Comment: Above I post my snippet code, how could I modify this to allow delegate returns selected value for combobox? thanks

Comment: Action does not allow a return value, in this case you will have to use a solution like @Will

Comment: Will solution doesn't work in ComboBox WPF Control. I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. The solution is create a custom delegate that returns the desired type like this:

```
    private object GetValueCB(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb)
    {
        object obj = null;


            if (!cb.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                obj = cb.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                  (MyDelegate)
                    delegate()
                    {
                        return (obj = cb.SelectedValue);
                    }
                );

                return obj;
            }
            else
            {
                return obj = cb.SelectedValue;
            }

    }

    public delegate object MyDelegate();
```