# Unable to access the UI control's value from non UI thread in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, silverlight-5.0

I am using silverlight 5 application for creating the Webresource for CRM 2011. In my code i am using BeginExecute and EndExecute methods for retriving availabe time slots for scheduling an appointment. No in EndExecute method i am getting all available time slot at which the meeting request can be made. Now when i get Available time slots i have to check all the start times of time slots with the start time selected on UI (on UI i have taken DateTimePicker) and for that i have to read value from DateTimePIcker. For this i have tried  DateTimePIcker.SelectedDateTime but it gives me error syaing "Invalid cross-thread access".

and i googled bout this problem and found UI operation can not be perofrmed with non UI thread. And they are suggesting to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(),

I have tried that also following is my code snipest

```
DateTime ScheduledDateTime = new DateTime();
    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ScheduledDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(MainDateTimePicker.SelectedDateTime));
```

but still in variable ScheduledDateTime  i am getting the value of "new DateTime()"

Can you suggest me a way to get value of DateTimePicker from the non UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is before you call the `BeginExecute` method, save the value of the `DateTimePicker` to a variable.  Then you can read this variable, even from another thread.

Comment: Steve, yes i have also followed this way. but i want to know some better way to do this. i mean i can not take global variable for such a things.it is not acceptable at all. Though i appreciate you time spent. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, doing this through some Lambda is a better option but my lambda is sub-par and my C# is even worst. Hopefully someone else can chime in here.

Comment: Try this link. It might get what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491927/how-to-return-a-value-with-dispatcher-invoke